# L4.2 Event: know where event got fired from?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a question regarding Events with Laravel 4.2...
I currently have an event listener on "auth.login"... some code lines are executed when user logins on web version... however I would like to execute a different action if the user logged via the API controller, example: ApiController@postLogin (my mobile version).

Code in my home controller:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => Input::get('login'), 'password' =>     Input::get('password')]) OR Auth::attempt(['username' => Input::get('login'), 'password' => Input::get('password')]))
    {
        return Redirect::intended(URL::route('dashboard.index'));
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::action('HomeController@getIndex')->with('poplogin', true)->with('badcredentials',true)->withInput();
    }
```

Code in global.php (event listener)

```
Event::listen('auth.login', function($user)
{
//Put Login_attemp in Database for Last activity, etc
$user->login_attemp()->create(['login_ip'=>$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],'login_time'=> date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time())]);
$user->last_logged = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time());
$user->save();
Session::flash('justlogged',true);
//other code that I didnt include..........

});
```

Code in my ApiController

```
public function getRefreshData() {
//check the token
    $token = Input::get('token');
    $username = Input::get('username');
    $user = User::where('api_token', $token)
                ->where('username', $username)
                ->first();
    if(!$user || !$token) {
        return Response::json([
            'error' => true,
            'message' => 'Invalid Token, please re login',
            'code' => 401],
            401
        );
    }

    Auth::login($user);

    //5 last Timesheets + tslines, for pre-load at log-in in phone memory
    //Not inserting possible creation dates between, to keep phone app 100% independent
    $timesheets = $user->timesheets()->orderBy('startdate', 'DESC')->take(10)->with('tslines')->get();

    //Other code that I didnt include
    );
    return $response;

}
```

I cannot control the execution of the event "auth.login" myself.. firing it manually with parameter would just double-fire the event (i think?)

Is there a way to detect where the event got fired from in the Event:listen and do not insert a "log-in attemp" (my code in event listener) each time I use the getRefreshData() function in my API? Yes, I need to log the user in my API function (for other code that isn't included)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found how I could 'bypass' the execution of the event listener when the event is fired from the ApiController, using the **Request::is()** function

From L4.2 Docs: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#request-information )..

My routes.php file is like so:

```
Route::controller('api/v1', 'ApiV1Controller');
```

And in my global.php (where I declare my event listener)

```
Event::listen('auth.login', function($user)
{
    if (!Request::is('api/*'))
    {
    //Code that is always executed at firing of event, except when from my API controllers

    //Put Login_attemp in Database for Last activity, etc
    $user->login_attemp()->create(['login_ip'=>$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],'login_time'=> date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time())]);
    $user->last_logged = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time());
    $user->save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: It seems to me that the most straightforward way to handle this is to check for the token in the Event listener.

```
Event::listen('auth.login', function($user)
{
    if (Input::has('token') && Input::has('username')) {
        //Put Login_attemp in Database for Last activity, etc
        $user->login_attemp()->create(['login_ip'=>$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],'login_time'=> date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time())]);
        $user->last_logged = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time());
        $user->save();
        Session::flash('justlogged',true);
        //other code that I didnt include..........
    }
});
```

I really would suggest, long term, looking at using the functionality demonstrated in the docs under [Accessing the Logged In User](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#authenticating-users), it's just going to make life easier.

Original response: It might be helpful if you posted more code, because I feel like maybe this is an instance where if we zoom out a little bit maybe there is a better way to deal with this situation. Possibly you need multiple actions, different listeners, etc.

For solving this issue though, it's easy, just pass in whatever additional data you need to via a parameter:

```
$response = Event::fire('auth.login', array($user, 'source' => 'ApiController@postLogin', 'mobile' => true));
```

Then you can set those parameters to the `$event` object that is passed to your listener.

Let me know if you have any further questions!

Comment: I have added code and more precision... If I Event::fire('auth.login') manually, will I just double-fire the event?? Laravel will automatically fire auth.login after an Auth:attemp or an Auth:login($user) but I don't want the event listener to execute from the APIController

Comment: After some more research, I finally found a clearer way to do it ^^
I self-answered my post
Thank-you for your help @Josh Rumbut